# Django rendering and submitting forms that are passed to from another form for email verification codes

Tags: python, django, http, authentication, routes

I want to accomplish the following, email verification with a verification code, not link

1. user signs up in a sign up form
2. user email is passed as context to a verification code entry form
3. user is sent a verification code
4. user enters the verification code in the verification code entry form
5. verification code is confirmed on the backend with the email sent from the first form context

So what I'm trying to do is that when the user accesses `example.com/signup` and fill out the form, I then render the `verification_code_entry_form`, and then they enter their verification code there. Finally once they submit that, they are redirected to login. However the difference between render and redirect is tripping me up.

in `urls.py`

```
path('signup', views.signup_page, name='signup'),
path('confirm_account', views.confirm_account, name="confirm_account"),
path('send_verification_code', views.send_verification_code, name="send_verification_code"),
```

in `views.py`

```
def signup_page(request):
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        try:
            ...backend authentication client work goes here

        except Exception as e:
            ...catch exceptions here
            messages.error(
                request,
                f'An unexpected error has occured.'
            )
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context)
        else:
            # Create user and verifications
            new_user.save()

            # Save the email in the context to use in the verification form
            context['email'] = email
            form = AccountConfirmationForm(request.POST or None)
            context['form'] = form
            messages.success(
                request,
                f'Account succesfully created for {email}. Please verify your e-mail, then login.'
            )
            
            # Redirect (render?) to verification code formation
            return render(request, 'confirm_account.html', context)

    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)


def confirm_account_verification_code(request):

    if not request.get('email'):
        """
        This represents a failure of the client to properly navigate to the verification code from signup or login
        So we should prompt them to reset their verification code and re-render with context
        """
        messages.error(request, f"An error occurred when processing your verification code request. Please try again")
        return redirect(request, "resend_verification_code")

    email = request.get('email')

    form = AccountConfirmationForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'email': email,
        'form': form,
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            verification_code = form.cleaned_data.get('verification_code')
            ...submit to backend
        except Exception as e:
           ...handle exceptions
            messages.error(
                request,
                f'An error occurred trying to confirm your account'
            )
            return render(request, "confirm_account.html", context)
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('signup_success') + '?first_time=yes')

    return render(request, "confirm_account.html", context)
```

Unfortunately my expected behavior isn't happening, though I acknowledge this doesn't seem quite right. Does django actually use the view function `confirm_account_verification_code()` when the `return render(request, 'confirm_account.html', context)` is called from the sign up form? I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.